# model load error in view file

Tags: magento

I have load custom module of mobile number in my magento site. When i try to load in separate view page it shows error.

here i have created new view file for mobile number in below customer/widget/mobile.phtml file

`<?php 
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_mobile')->setObject($this->getFormData())->toHtml() 
?>`

Fatal error: Call to a member function setObject() on a non-object in /var/rooja/app/design/frontend/default/rooja/template/customer/form/register.phtml on line 195.

1. Can anyone explain the reason for this error?
2. How I can debug this error?

thanks 
Prakash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your `->createBlock('customer/widget_mobile')` call is not creating and returning a block object as you are expecting. So when you are chaining the setObject call, there is no object for it to `setObject` against.

Check that the block `customer/widget_module` actually exists first.  Also check your exception log as the createBlock method in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php` (around line 434) should throw an exception if it cant create the block.